# jquery if else, why does not work?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

In  the following function it goes through the if and the else, why is that?

```
function test(){
        $(".notEmpty").each(function() {
         if($(this).val() === ""){
            alert("Empty Fields!!");
            return;
           }
         else{
                AddRow_OnButtonClick('tblMedicationDetail',6);
              }
     });

}
```

Is there any if and else statement on jquery that I am not aware of?

AddRow_OnButtonClick is a function to add a new row with 6 textboxes which I am attaching a className 'notEmpty' if any of the text boxes are empty the function AddRow_OnButtonClick should not be called and an alert should pop up.

I dont know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Tell me this is one of those bobince-inspired joke questions.

Comment: FAPOC [ **F** or **A** **P** oint **O** f **C** larification]: Cesar; does it go through the `if` and the `else` for every single row (does it both alert "Empty Fields!!" **and** run the `AddRow_OnButtonClick` for each row.)?

Comment: What do you mean by "it goes through the if and the else?"  What is the expected behavior, and how is it actually behaving?

Comment: Sorry I added a bit more details of what is the function meant to be doing. I hope it clarifies what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the existing two answers leads me to believe this will work:

```
var emptyFields = false;

function test(){
    emptyFields = false;
    $(".notEmpty").each(function() {
        if($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            emptyFields = true;
            return false; // break out of the each-loop
        } 
    });
    if (emptyFields) {
        alert("Empty Fields!!");
    } else {
        AddRow_OnButtonClick("tblMedicationDetail",6);
    }
}
```

The basic idea is that you need to use your `.each` call to only determine if a field is empty. After this, you can deal with the information using the `if else` statement.

Comment: See my edit - you can just do `return false` and you don't need to maintain a status variable.

Comment: @Skilldrick: Thanks for the tip, I'm not much a of jQuery developer yet so it's good to know these things.

Comment: That's it!!!, but there is still a problem, if the user types a space, it will consider as not empty, space should not be consider as not empty, but empty field. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I considered this approach, but I remembered reading something about returning from the `.each` early. It is a bit confusing though - `return` acts like `continue` would in a loop, and `return false` acts like `return` usually would. brainache...

Comment: Added the `$.trim()` method around the `.val()` line to ensure it classes whitespace as an empty field. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: @Skilldrick: when `return false` is used, how do I read the result? It looks to me that `.each` returns a `jQuery` object, but I've no idea how the result is stored within this

Answer (score 3):

The `return` statement only returns from the function supplied to `.each`. I suspect the problem you're having is that you want to return from `test()`. As it is, after you return from the inner function you'll still apply the inner function to the rest of the elements.

If I'm right, and you want to break out of the `.each()` altogether, put `return false` instead ([see jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)).

Answer (score 0):

I've structured your code to make it a little more readable, but I'm not sure why both the *if* and the *else* are both being called:

```
function test(){
    $(".notEmpty").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() === ""){
            alert("Empty Fields!!");
            return;
        } else {
            AddRow_OnButtonClick("tblMedicationDetail",6);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).val() == ""){
```

2 equals signs not 3 - That MIGHT be your problem...?

Comment: Worth a shot, I see the answer above now :)